# Why Im getting a Unexpected keyword INTERVAL in this sql when trying to run it in Big Query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I got this sql and Im trying to run it in BigQuery. Im getting this error:

Unexpected keyword INTERVAL

```
SELECT studio."Location" as location ,CONCAT(users.first_name, ',', users.last_name) AS username , COUNT(events.created_at) AS events    
FROM xxx    
JOIN zzz ON z_kf_asset = asset.z_kp    
JOIN client ON production.z_kf_client = client.z_kp    
JOIN studio ON client.z_kf_studio = studio.z_kp    
JOIN events ON events.asset_id = asset.z_kp    
JOIN users ON events.user_id = users."id"    
WHERE post_history IS NOT NULL    
AND events.created_at BETWEEN LOCALTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '7 days' AND LOCALTIMESTAMP    
AND client.display_name = 'xxxxx'    
AND events.description = 'xxxxxxxx'    
GROUP BY location, username
```

Would appreciate any help

Comment: I don't think BigQuery supports date math like that (i.e. use of the `-` operator). Also `'7 days'` should be `7 day`. Try `DATE_SUB(LOCALTIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 7 DAY)`

Comment: Thank you , it worked!!! what about this one AND client.display_name = 'xxxxx' , aparently the = is not accepted.

Comment: Not getting it. So , should be  "AND events.created_at BETWEEN DATE_SUB(LOCALTIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND LOCALTIMESTAMP

AND client.display_name = 'xxx'

AND events.description = 'xxxx'

?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Nick gave the right answer in the comments. Transcribing here for completeness:

Instead of:

```
localtimestamp - INTERVAL '7 days'
```

Do:

```
TIMESTAMP_SUB(localtimestamp, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

For example:

```
SELECT '2018-01-9' BETWEEN TIMESTAMP_SUB(localtimestamp, INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND localtimestamp
FROM (SELECT TIMESTAMP('2018-01-15') localtimestamp)
```